# MySQL insert row with date

Tags: mysql, sql, database, insert

```
use TREND_INFORMATION

INSERT INTO log_index_level_1
(LOG_INDEX, LOT_ID, WAFER_ID, MAP_REV, PROBE_DATE)
(42, "2819893.003", "9893-06", "PR20", "2013-07-13");
```

I keep getting the following error, and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

The column types are int , varchar, varchar, varchar, and date , respectively.

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL s
>       er version for the right syntax to use near '42, "asdfasfasf", "asdfas", "tes", '2013-07-13')' at line 3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing the keyword `VALUES`

```
INSERT INTO log_index_level_1
(LOG_INDEX, LOT_ID, WAFER_ID, MAP_REV, PROBE_DATE)
VALUES -- <-- That's what you're missing
(42, "2819893.003", "9893-06", "PR20", "2013-07-13");
```

Answer (score 3):

You forgot the `VALUES` keyword

```
INSERT INTO log_index_level_1 (LOG_INDEX, LOT_ID, WAFER_ID, MAP_REV, PROBE_DATE)
VALUES (42, '2819893.003', '9893-06', 'PR20', '2013-07-13');
```